# List blobs in Azure storage container via URL

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a storage account set up and a single container in it. The access level is set to public and I can access the individual blobs as so:

`https://img.blob.core.windows.net/images/name_of_blob`

However, when I try to access the URL of the container (`images`) directly:

`https://img.blob.core.windows.net/images/`

I get this response:

```
<Error>
  <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
  <Message>The specified resource does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

Is there a way to get a list of all the blobs within the container through a URL request?

Comment: How about using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it, I've added my comment and as answer. It would be good if you could accept it to that your question shows as resolved for other users. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs)?

Something like:

```
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list
```

Be sure to pass in any required headers as per the documentation linked above.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the container, the public access level must have been set at 'Blob'. If you set the public access level at 'Container' from the dropdown, you should be able to access the list.